# Subset Sum using the "Meet in the Middle" Technique

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I had a problem while I was reading the "Meet in the Middle" part of "Competitive Programmer's Handbook" (by Antti Laaksonen).

The book states an example question as follow (subset sum):

> Consider a problem where we are given a list of n numbers and a number x, and we want to find if it's possible to choose some numbers from the list so that their sum is x. For example, given the list [2, 4, 5, 9] and x = 15, we can choose the numbers [2, 4, 9] to form 15.

The algorithm first divides the list into two sets A, B such that both of them contain half of the numbers, then it generates sorted lists S<sub>A</sub> and S<sub>B</sub>, which are all the possible sums of subsets from A and from B, respectively. Afterwards, we can use a two-pointer algorithm (or perhaps binary search) to "merge" the results from S<sub>A</sub> and S<sub>B</sub>.

My problem is about the time complexity of this problem. Again, the book states that:

> First, we generate *sorted* lists S<sub>A</sub> and S<sub>B</sub>, which can be done in O(*2<sup>n/2</sup>*).

Yet from my point of view, I'll need to find generate all sums in S<sub>A</sub>, which already takes O(n*2<sup>n/2</sup>*). And since there are 2<sup>n/2</sup> elements in S<sub>A</sub>, sorting S<sub>A</sub> would take O(2<sup>n/2</sup>log(2<sup>n/2</sup>))=O(n2<sup>n/2</sup>). How is it possible to do this in O(2<sup>n/2</sup>)?

Thanks for you help!!!

Comment: If n is not too large, you can use a counting sort. Concerning generation of the sums of A, I don't understand why you need O(n 2^n/2) and not O(2^n/2). This is related to the method you use to generate the sums. You may describe your method

Comment: In practice, if you first sort A and B, and if you iteratively generate the sums, then the sorting can be performed by merging, and complexity remains O(2^n/2)

Comment: @Damien: Please note that all computers, and most humans, parse *2^n/2* as *(2^n)/2*, and not *2^(n/2)*.

Comment: This question has an answer here: [https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99450/subset-sum-exponential-solution-how-does-the-sorting-work](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99450/subset-sum-exponential-solution-how-does-the-sorting-work)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Thanks for you answer! I know it now!